# C++ Return Value from function not same as that value in function

Tags: c++

So, I am trying to implement trie structure, and so far everything works fine, except the following:

When using the count_words function, I print the result just before returning it, and that result is correct, but when I print it in main, it becomes some unknown strange integer value.

```
typedef struct trie {
    int words;
    int prefixes;
    struct trie *characters[26];
} node;

int find_character_location(int ascii) {
    return ascii-97;
}

node * initialize() {
    node * new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->words = 0;
    new_node->prefixes = 0;

    //all english alphabet characters
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {
        new_node->characters[i] = NULL;
    }

    return new_node;
}

//when adding string use only english lowercase letters
//a=97 b=98 ... z=122
void add_string(node * root, string str) {
    int str_size = str.size();

    if(str_size == 0) {
        root->words++;
        return;
    }
    else {
        int position = find_character_location(str[0]);
        root->prefixes++;    //character doesnt exists
        if(root->characters[position] == NULL) {
            root->characters[position] = initialize();
    }
    add_string(root->characters[position],
    str_size==1?"":   str.substr(1));
    }
}

int count_prefixes(node *root, string prefix) {
    int str_size = prefix.size();

    if(prefix == "") {
        cout<<"number of prefixes: "<<(root->prefixes)<<endl;
        return (*root).prefixes;
    }

    int position = find_character_location(prefix[0]);

//character exists
if(root->characters[position] != NULL) {
    count_prefixes(
    root->characters[position],str_size==1?"":prefix.substr(1));

    }
    else {
        cout<<"no prefixes, returning 0"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
}


int count_words(node *root, string str) {
    int str_size = str.size();

    if(str == "") {
        cout<<"Number of words: "<<root->words<<endl;
        int ret = root->words;
        return (int)ret;
}

int position = find_character_location(str[0]);

//that character exists
if(root->characters[position] != NULL) {
    count_words(root->characters[position], 
    str_size==1 ? "" :  str.substr(1));

    }
    else {
        cout<<"no words, returning 0"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
}


int main() {

    node * root;
    root = initialize();

    add_string(root, "tomislav");
    add_string(root, "tomislav");
    add_string(root, "tomislav");
    add_string(root, "todoric");
    add_string(root, "tomahawk");
    add_string(root, "tosad");
    add_string(root, "tomo");

    cout<<"Counting words"<<count_words(root, "tomislav");
    return 0;
}
```

So for example, for count_words(root, "tomislav") in the function count_words it is printed 3, but in main it is printed 9872106

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Start by indenting this code correctly.

Comment: Not sure if related to your problem, but if `str` isn't empty, and there are words in your list, you don't, actually, return anything. The `then` clause of `if(root->characters[position] != NULL)` statement does not contain `return` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple calls to `count_words` active (that's how recursion works) but only the last one actually returns a value.

Suppose we're searching for "to". `main` will call `count_words` with "to" and the root node. That will call `count_words` with "o" and the "t" node. That will call `count_words` with "" and the "to" node.

The last call prints "Number of words: 7" and then returns 7 to the second-to-last call. The middle call ignores this return value, and doesn't return a value, so its return value is garbage. The first call ignores this garbage return value, and doesn't return a value, so its return value is garbage too (possibly different garbage). Then `main` prints the return value from the first call, which was garbage.

Your intermediate calls need to return something. Probably you just want to return whatever the next call returned, so add `return` in front of `count_words(root->characters[position],str_size==1?"":prefix.substr(1));`. (And similarly for `count_prefixes`)

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying, you all pointed out to the same thing which was correct, it is actually a silly mistake but what you gonna do.

@immibis your answer was the most descriptive so that's why I am marking it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
int count_words(node *root, string str) {
    int str_size = str.size();

    if(str == "") {
        cout<<"Number of words: "<<root->words<<endl;
        int ret = root->words;
        return (int)ret;
    }

    int position = find_character_location(str[0]);

    if(root->characters[position] != NULL) {
        count_words(root->characters[position], 
        str_size==1 ? "" :  str.substr(1));
        //*********
    }
    else {
        cout<<"no words, returning 0"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Where I marked with ***, you're not returning anything.
This leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`count_words` doesn't always return a value, meaning, sometimes, you'll end up giving the caller whatever nonsense is on the stack. The code is a bit hard to read because of your indentation, but I suspect you mean for

```
if(root->characters[position] != NULL) {
    count_words(root->characters[position], 
    str_size==1 ? "" :  str.substr(1));

    }
```

to be

```
if(root->characters[position] != NULL) {
    return count_words(root->characters[position], 
    str_size==1 ? "" :  str.substr(1));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set your compiler's warnings and errors to the maximum. In two functions (`count_prefixes()` and `count_words()`) you have control paths that terminate without **return**ing a value. Fix those and your program will work correctly.